# How to make a ggdag plot (Directed Acyclic Graphs in R) of data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a data frame that wants to make a **ggdagplot** in R.
this is the sample of data:

```
structure(list(NMSUKU = c("Aceh/ Achin/ Akhir/ Asji/ A-Tse/ Ureung Aceh", 
"Alas", "Aneuk Jamee", "Gayo", "Gayo Lut", "Gayo Luwes", "Gayo Serbe Jadi", 
"Kluet", "Simeulue", "Simeulue", "Simeulue", "Singkil", "Tamiang"
), TopLang = c("1_Aceh/ Acheh/ Achi", "9_Alas", "4_Aceh Jamee", 
"10_Gajo/ Gayo", "10_Gajo/ Gayo", "10_Gajo/ Gayo", "10_Gajo/ Gayo", 
"5_Aceh Kluet", "11_Long Bano/ Simalur/ Simeuloe/ Simeulue/ Simulul", 
"7_Aceh Simeleu Barat", "8_Aceh Simeleu Tengah", "3_Aceh Hulu Singkil", 
"14_Tamiang"), language = c("1_Aceh/ Acheh/ Achi", "9_Alas", 
"4_Aceh Jamee", "10_Gajo/ Gayo", "10_Gajo/ Gayo", "10_Gajo/ Gayo", 
"10_Gajo/ Gayo", "5_Aceh Kluet", "11_Long Bano/ Simalur/ Simeuloe/ Simeulue/ Simulul", 
"7_Aceh Simeleu Barat", "8_Aceh Simeleu Tengah", "3_Aceh Hulu Singkil", 
"14_Tamiang")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

[image: I want to get like this]

Comment: What packages and code have you tried so far? [MRE] provides tips for asking questions.

Comment: @Peter, the ` ggdag package` is using for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a first approach using `igraph`. You will have to tweak the visualisation to your desired output..

```
library(igraph)
# Problem is that some column entries are similar, so they are seen
# as the same node. I added some spaces at the end of 2nd 
# and 3rd columnto prevent this
df$TopLang  <- paste0(df$TopLang, " ")
df$language <- paste0(df$language, "  ")
# Create graph
m <- as.matrix(df)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(rbind(m[,1:2], m[,2:3]), directed = TRUE)
l <- layout_with_sugiyama(g)
# plot
plot(g, layout=-l$layout[,2:1], edge.arrow.size = 0.4)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to have just one line from 10_Gajo/Gayo to 10_Gajo/Gayo?

Comment: `igraph::simplify()` will help. Set the `remove.duplicates`-argument to 'TRUE' (=default)